# Using accents in Jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time find an answer to this. I am working on a french website and started writing my jquery coding in french for certian variables but seems to be causing more problems than anything.

For example here is a variable I was trying to create:

```
var GDI_Priorité = result.Priorité;
```

I start getting errors saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

When I look at the console my variable comes back as:

```
var GDI_PrioritÃ© = result.PrioritÃ©;
```

I looked trough google and this site but cant seem to find an answer to why its doing it. My guess would be that jquery just aint compatible with accents and I might need to filter my var everytime I need an accent.

Looking for any advice at this point to know if I can somehow still keep accents in my code.

Comment: there is no jQuery variables... only javascript one's

Comment: It seems the site's encoding is not set to UTF8. It should work if you fix that. And as said, jQuery is a library for JavaScript, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

Answer (score 2):

Following Felix Kling`s comment about the encoding of the page being off. I double checked and indeed my page was set to UTF-8 but was still having problems loading accents. So a light went up in my head, it seems that my editor notepad++ was not coding in UTF-8 wich caused this whole mess. Now things are much better :)

Comment: Ah yeah. Good catch :)